# How automatically draw lines across a 360 degree azimuth for all points in a feature layer at a given distance in ArcGIS Pro v3.x

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, vector

I am having some difficulty with a current project. I would like to create a total of 360 lines (lines at every bearing) of a given distance and iterate the line drawing across all points in the feature layer. I am trying to use ModelBuilder.  However the "Bearing Field" with the "Bearing Distance to Line", tool (a numeric input) requires a field contained within the input feature layer, i.e., the corresponding record for the point. I cannot use any of iterators on csv the table I built with the azimuth degrees because the ModelBuilder only accepting fields/derivatives of those fields belonging to the input layer's attribute table.

Is there a way around this or do I have to modify the tool and import it as my own custom tool within the ModelBuilder workflow?

Comment: If you have arcmap you can use my tool that I had uploaded to the esri code sharing website [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2b0c54fe415641e7af8490c4ba7d4bcf). It _might_ work for ArcPro but no guarantees.

Comment: @Hornbydd it worked! Thank you so much. All that was needed was updating some syntax for python 3.10, but once that was done, it worked like any other arc pro toolbox.

Comment: Glad it has helped, not too much code tweaking I hope?

Comment: @Hornbydd nope! 
Line 101 string.split -> str.split.
Line 141 dictPolylines.iteritems() -> dictPolylines.items()

I think that was it.
Thanks again for the tool, it's definitely forward compatible with ArcPro.